# how to make an external java library automatically added when i send the project to any person ?

Tags: java, libraries

i am working on a project for the college and i want to add jcalendar-1.4 library to use it in GUI but when i send the project to any one they need to import the library manually is there is anyway to make the library added automatically so my TA does not have to added because the jcalendar disappears from the GUI if the library is not added

Answer (score 1):

Use Maven or any other dependency management tool (Gradle,Ivy and some more).

https://maven.apache.org/